# How to let text in Android Webview fit different screen size?

Tags: android

I have an application contains a webview. When I run this application on phones, it works well. However, if I run it on tablet, the text it displayed is a little smaller to show. I hope if anyone has a solution, let the text inside webview will automatic increase or descreas their size to fit different screen. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries. Change the font size according to the screen width. for instance,

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    html {
        font-size: [font size for tablet]
    }
}
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    html {
        font-size: [font size for large mobile]
    }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    html {
        font-size: [font size for smaller mobile]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control your WebView content by using metadata. Here is reference guide, [Targeting Screens from Web Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html)!